# Protect Android Native Librays

Tags: java, android, security, shared-libraries

#### The Problem

I have a lot of shared librays (.so) that I need for my project. But I noticed that everyone can extract the apk file and rename it to .zip, and can copy and use the shared librays.

#### What I tried

I tried to encrypt the shared librays and copy them later to the libs Folder, but this doesn't work because when the app get's installed the libs gets created, and you can never change it. I also tried to use an .aar file, but I do also not work.